# Run a specific dialog if user's inactivity period exceeds a limit

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have to check if the user inactivity period exceeds a limit upon receiving each message from the user and run a dialog if so. How can I achieve this that in a bot composed in bot composer(node.js)?

I tried using middleware, but that did not work?

Can we achieve this using custom adapter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using the ui based sdk for building this bot.